# Force download file with Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, components, readfile

I'm trying to force the download of a file in a custom component in Joomla 3. The action of my controller has this code :

```
header ( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename ( $file ) );
header ( 'Expires: 0' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header ( 'Pragma: public' );
header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $file ) );
readfile ( $file );
exit();
```

$file is the absolute path to the file and Apache has "read rights".

I tested the code in an isolated file and it works fine.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
ob_clean(); 
flush();
```

Before **readfile**($file) solved my problem.